# Splitting up wchar_t array/string into two different arrays/strings

Tags: c++, string, split

I have searched around before and couldn't really find a clean cut answer about this subject,  what I want in simple terms is this:

Drag and drop feature gives me a directory with the filename.

```
C:\Users\chaos\Desktop\Game Launcher V1.0.exe
```

I need to make this one string into two different strings so it would do this

```
Directory: C:\Users\chaos\Desktop\

FileName: Game Launcher V1.0.exe
```

I figured there was foruma for a loop to do this, so I was wondering what your input on this situation would be, I'd love to hear it. Thanks :)

I am on Windows using Visual Studio 2015. (UTF16)

Comment: Is this UTF16 or something else? And what type (wstring, an array...)?

Comment: What environment do You use. Show code used in this d&d context

Comment: I just updated main post, Windows on Visual Studio 2015.  @Jacek Cz

I will post the code in a sec I am loading VS.

Comment: Your edit doesn't help much. Again what type is it? And with Windows, UTF16 is likely, but not necessarily true, and if you don't know what UTF16 is, take it as a hint to research.

Comment: Sigh. Well, you have 3 close votes already, 2 more to go. [Btw., it's clear as the day that you don't understand what UTF16 means, if you list it together with your IDE]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on Windows, have a look at the [`PathRemoveFileSpec()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748.aspx), [`PathStripPath()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773756.aspx), and [`PathFindFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773589.aspx) functions, eg:

```
LPTSTR szFullFilename = ...; // value from drag&drop
int iLength = lstrlen(szFullFilename);

LPTSTR szDirectory = new TCHAR[iLength+1];
lstrcpy(szDirectory, szFullFilename);
PathRemoveFileSpec(szDirectory);

LPTSTR szFileName = new TCHAR[iLength+1];
lstrcpy(szFileName, szFullFilename);
PathStripPath(szFileName);

// use szDirectory and szFileName as needed...

delete[] szDirectory;
delete[] szFileName;
```

```
LPTSTR szFullFilename = ...; // value from drag&drop
int iLength = lstrlen(szFullFilename);

LPTSTR szDirectory = new TCHAR[iLength];
lstrcpy(szDirectory, szFullFilename);

LPTSTR szFileName = PathFindFileName(szDirectory);
if (szFileName != szDirectory)
    *(szFileName-1) = 0;

// use szDirectory and szFileName as needed...

delete[] szDirectory;
```